# How to add reference to all DLLs in folder in Blob Triggered Azure Function V 1.x?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, csx

I have created Blob Triggered Azure Function. I have added some DLLs in a folder named "ExternalAssemblies".
If I have 3 DLLs in that folder I have to reference them with following lines at the top of my function:

```
#r "..\ExternalAssemblies\Assembly1.dll"
#r "..\ExternalAssemblies\Assembly2.dll"
#r "..\ExternalAssemblies\Assembly3.dll"
```

This became very tedious when I have many DLLs.

Is there any way by which I can just reference the "ExternalAssemblies" folder and all DLLs in it gets referred?

Thank You

Comment: Do you mind accepting the suggestion since it's by design that we are not able to load the folder for convenience?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no such method to load the folder instead of assemblies inside.

If `ExternalAssemblies` are custom assemblies, we may have to rely on the tedious directives. If the assemblies are from Nuget packages, we could turn to `project.json` to install them. Click `View files` on the right of function code panel, `Add` new file `project.json` with structure below. Don't forget to remove `#r` directives which are invalid for Nuget installed packages.

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "<Nuget package name>": "<Version>"
      }
    }
   }
}
```